# Workbook_sheetChange crash when cell is open and another worksheet is selected

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I am working on an Excel file for operator on a machine, so it need to be armored.

I am running on a small bug link to a specific scenario:

When i edit a cell from the specified range from my `Workbook_sheetChange` and click on another sheet the code crash and give a 1004, i know why (wrong objet since i produce a cross-sheet `_Global` link) but i dont know how to avoid it. I looked trough Stack and google but didnt found anything, also i have an mec engereeing programming course so i dont know a lot about object and event.

Heres my code :

```
Sub Workbook_sheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4:C8")) Is Nothing Then 'Si changement dans les cellules "nom employé"

Call Employe ' Appel Macro pour nom automatique

End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U18:V42")) Is Nothing Then

Call tritroughsheets ' Macro tri des temps d'arret

End If

End Sub
```

In this case for exemple if C4 is in edit mode and in Sheet1 and the operator click on Sheet2 by mistake it'll pop-up an error message (which we dont want operator to deal with)

Im looking for lines like

```
If(cell is being edited) Then
dont run my stuff till its close
End if
```

Any idea?

Thx, (wear mask boïs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing of

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4:C8")) Is Nothing
```

with:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, sh.Range("C4:C8")) Is Nothing 'exactly qualifies/references the range to the sh worksheet...
```

VBA tries an intersection between ranges in two different worksheets. When remained in the worksheet, `Range("C4:C8")` refers to the (correct) **active sheet**. When you move from a cell to another worksheet, **without changing anything in the analyzed range**, the event is not triggered... So, not the cell editing is the problem.

Comment: @Jérôme: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to locate bugs without seeing the subroutines being called.  I would suggest disabling and re-enabling events while your sub is running:

```
Sub Workbook_sheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4:C8")) Is Nothing Then 'Si changement dans les cellules "nom employé"
            Call Employe ' Appel Macro pour nom automatique
        End If
        
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U18:V42")) Is Nothing Then
            Call tritroughsheets ' Macro tri des temps d'arret
        End If
        
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it common to use it on every sub ur having problem with or it can cause other problems? If its a good practice il add it to my futur code.